# Using Ionic 4 tabs somewhere other than root

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am having trouble showing tabs on a different route using the tabs starter project. I started a new tabs project:

`ionic start "tabs-example" tabs --type=angular`

and running it, the tabs work right away. I created a new page called `home` (using `ionic generate page`) and I want that to be the root page which I got working by updating the routes below.

I adjusted the `app-routing.module.ts` to look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'home/tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
];
```

When I serve the app, I see my `home.page.html` contents which is simply:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <a href="/home/tabs">tabs</a>
</ion-content>
```

When I click the anchor link the url changes, however, it just goes to a white screen with no errors in the console.

The only change I did to the `tabs.router.module.ts` was update the URLs which I am guessing I did incorrectly, but cant seem to figure out the issue.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home/tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/home/tabs',
    redirectTo: '/home/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this persisted across from the older ionics but I think you need to remove the / in the url e.g `<a href="home/tabs">tabs</a>`

Comment: @johnny5 if I do that, then the url will just be /tabs which wont match any route, right?

Comment: Hmm? In older versions of angular the if you added the slash it assumed you were part of the parent route e.g `/home/tabs => home/home/tabs` so removing the / from the beginning of the url in the anchor might work but I don't have an ionic project infront of me so you'll have to test it out

Comment: @johnny5 gotcha..well removing it produces `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs'` when I click the URL

Comment: sorry that was my best guess :/

Comment: @johnny5 ah I got it! The trick is not use `href` but instead use `routerLink` and the link is indeed `routerLink="tabs"` and not `home/tabs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a router link to reference instead of an href

```
<a routerLink="tabs">Tabs</a>
```